# Nginx redirect to another domain doesn't work as expected

Tags: nginx

I have a rails app with nginx and puma and the rails app respond to

```
app.example.org
```

I need to redirect `https://www.example.org` and `https://example.org` to another domain

I have in nginx config this block to redirect

```
server {
  server_name www.example.org;
  return 301 https://www.redirectdomain.com/$request_uri;
}
```

And this block for the app

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name app.example.org;
  return 301 https://app.example.org$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.org/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.org/privkey.pem;
  server_name app.example.org;
  root /home/deploy/apps/example_production/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_app.example.org;
}
```

The redirect doesn't work: if I use `www.example.org` it redirect to `app.example.org` and not to `https://www.redirectdomain.com`

Why?

Comment: The first server block in your question listens on port 80, so will only receive connections using `http` and not `https`.

Answer (score 0):

in the `www.example.org` block, You are not listening on any ports so it is basically ignored.

The next block it encounters is for `app.example.org` which is configured to listen for requests on port 80.

In your DNS settings, You either have a CNAME or A/AAAA records pointing requests made to `www.example.org` and `app.example.org` to the same nginx instance.

This means, It is not redirecting requests from `www.example.org` -> `app.example.org`. It's just what's happening because of a bug in your configuration.

Add a `listen` statement in the `www.example.org` block and it should work.